I created a new React-Native app, Why is my build failing already?
I am using MacOS Monterey version 12.6, ruby version 3.3.0, CocoaPods version 1.15.2.
When I create a new project(npx react-native@latest init newApp), I am prompted to install CocoaPods, even though I have it already installed. If I choose yes I receive the following error installing CocoaPods dependencies. If I choose no, then I do not receive any error: 
When I execute the command npm run iOS, the Metro server successfully initiates, however the app build fails with the following error:
Please help me find what I am missing or have incorrectly installed? I have tried different versions of ruby, version 2.7.5, 2.6.8, and 3.0.0. Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

How did you install cocoa pods? With sudo gem install cocoapods or with brew install cocoapods.

@MichaelBahl I used Homebrew and ran the command brew install cocoapods I have an M1 chip so it was a little difficult to install.


Do not install cocoa pods while project initial
Try to install pods from project root and not the iOS folder npc pod-install
What returns which pod ?

